# How do I rebase and squash commits in git?

Tags: git

I am new to git. I have used basic commands like `git pull`, `git push`, `git checkout` a branch but never do a squash the commits into a single commit and never done a rebase.
My lead developer has asked me to use an old checkout branch (been there for 3 months).
I have done the changes on that branch but need to rebase and squash a bit confused as to how exactly it is done.
I have used the following it failed.

`git rebase origin master`

`git push`

Comment: you might want to have a look at [learngitbranching](https://learngitbranching.js.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git fetch`

`git log`

git fetch and git log are just to make sure you are updated and you can see the log to make sure your rebase worked correctly.

`git rebase -i origin/master`

After you do a git rebase -i origin/master in the vi editor use the option fixup to squash all commits which you don't want (replace pickup by fixup)

`git status`

If there are any conflicts use git add . and git rebase --continue otherwise you can ignore below two step. (being old branch i think there are going to be conflicts)

`git add .`

`git rebase --continue`

`git log`

Just check logs to make sure your commits are at correct place using git log this step is not needed its optional.

You will have to use a force push.

`git push -f`